# jbuilder template skipped when pushing data into a content_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder, content-tag

I'm using jbuilder to build json. When I hit my controller with a `.json` request, it works perfectly and I get the appropriate json response. Now I am trying to shove the json into a html5 data attribute (so as to save me the second request to get json). This is all supported within `content_tag`. My `content_tag` looks like:

```
<%= content_tag "section", id: "people-container", data: { people: @people } do %>
  Loading people...
<% end %>
```

Within the `content_tag` it no longer hits the jbuilder template that I've put together, instead it appears to call the default `to_json` on the array of objects (`@people`). As such I don't get the json that I do when hitting `.json`. Is there a way to force this to go through jbuilder?